# Launch 3 distinct functions with arguments at the same time

Tags: python, parallel-processing, arguments, cx-oracle

I would like to start 3 distinct functions at the same time on machine with multiple cores. Each function launches an extensive data query to separate databases using the same module (cx_Oracle) and each function is called with some arguments. How could this be accomplished?

I have read a bit on parallel computing with Python but ProcessPoolExecutor always returns BrokenProcessPool error. The script is saved (reported as an issue in other SE item).

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(3) as executor:
        future_1 = executor.submit(query_1, arg1)
        future_2 = executor.submit(query_2, arg2)
        future_3 = executor.submit(query_3, arg3)
    result_1 = future_1.result()
    result_2 = future_2.result()
    result_3 = future_3.result()

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Have you seen something similar? A reference to other thread or an example of three distinct calls with arguments is enough for me. I have also tried multiprocessing but not successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cx_Oracle sample [Threads.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/Threads.py) shows running two statements in different threads:

```
. . .
def TheLongQuery():
     . . .

def DoALock():
    . . .


thread1 = threading.Thread(None, TheLongQuery)
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(None, DoALock)
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Comment: I tested this with two Oracle queries to separate databases but the runtime is same as when I run them one after another. I tried with smaller queries (100 MB) and larger ones (2 GB). Not sure if speed of saving data to memory is already maxed out when I run queries sequentially. I  tried it also with functions that use different modules (cx_oracle and pymssql) without success.

Comment: I mark as accepted as I assume this allows parallel processing, albeit performance is not affected.